# How to order drawing of objects on the canvas?

Tags: javascript

I want to create a windrose with a compass image overlayed by wind direction lines. Cobbled together from other posts from stackoverflow I have created the following code.  My problem is that the line drawing is overwritten by the background image.  Is there some way I can specify the order of display.

Thanks

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

<canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
<script>
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    //
    var background = new Image();
     background.src = "https://clipground.com/images/windrose-clipart-15.jpg";
    background.onload = () => {
        ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, 300, 300);
    }
    ctx.moveTo(150, 150); ctx.lineTo(207, 11);
    ctx.lineWidth = 5;
    ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
    ctx.stroke();
</script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Set the background in canvas using layer (zIndex)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14991286/set-the-background-in-canvas-using-layer-zindex)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently you:

1. Set the image loading
2. Draw on the canvas
3. Draw the image on the canvas once it is loaded

You need to draw the image *first*.

So move the rest of your drawing instructions so they also wait for the image to load.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <canvas id="myCanvas" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
  <script>
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    //
    var background = new Image();
    background.src = "https://clipground.com/images/windrose-clipart-15.jpg";
    background.onload = () => {
      ctx.drawImage(background, 0, 0, 300, 300);
      ctx.moveTo(150, 150);
      ctx.lineTo(207, 11);
      ctx.lineWidth = 5;
      ctx.strokeStyle = "black";
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```